# how to copy non duplicate elements from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, typescript, arraylist

how to copy non duplicate elements from multiple arrays which will be dynamic

I want to make length of each **graphmonthdata** same.
for example **graphmonthdata[2]** length is 4 so i want to make its length whichever is highest length in nested array with missing values from another nested array and vice versa.
basically all  nested array should have same length and same elements by adding missing elements from another nested array

in javascript or c# please help Thank You!

example nested array

```
 graphmonthdata = [
    [
        "Bug Fixing",
        "Deployment",
        "Design",
        "Development",
        "Documentation",
        "Downtime",
        "Learning & Skill Upgrade",
        "Meetings",
        "Project Management",
        "Requirement Understanding",
        "Review",
        "Support",
        "Testing"
    ],
    [
        "Bug Fixing",
        "Deployment",
        "Development",
        "Documentation",
        "Meetings",
        "Review",
        "Support",
        "Testing",
        "UAT/Prod. Fixes"
    ],
    [
        "Meetings",
        "Organisational Activity",
        "Planned/Unplanned Leave",
        "Testing"
    ]
]
```

the final array should look like this

```
 graphmonthdata = 
[
    [
        "Bug Fixing",
        "Deployment",
        "Design",
        "Development",
        "Documentation",
        "Downtime",
        "Learning & Skill Upgrade",
        "Meetings",
        "Organisational Activity",
        "Planned/Unplanned Leave",
        "Project Management",
        "Requirement Understanding",
        "Review",
        "Support",
        "Testing",
        "UAT/Prod. Fixes"
    ],
    [
        "Bug Fixing",
        "Deployment",
        "Design",
        "Development",
        "Documentation",
        "Downtime",
        "Learning & Skill Upgrade",
        "Meetings",
        "Organisational Activity",
        "Planned/Unplanned Leave",
        "Project Management",
        "Requirement Understanding",
        "Review",
        "Support",
        "Testing",
        "UAT/Prod. Fixes"
    ],
    [
        "Bug Fixing",
        "Deployment",
        "Design",
        "Development",
        "Documentation",
        "Downtime",
        "Learning & Skill Upgrade",
        "Meetings",
        "Organisational Activity",
        "Planned/Unplanned Leave",
        "Project Management",
        "Requirement Understanding",
        "Review",
        "Support",
        "Testing",
        "UAT/Prod. Fixes"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: What if your largest inner array does not contain items from _smaller_ arrys. E.g. `[['a','b','c'], ['a'], ['b'], ['d']]`. What's supposed to be the output in that case?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it should get filled with missing values from smaller arrays for example  the longest array here is  graphmonthdata[0] doesnt have the value from graphmonthdata[2] which is "Planned/Unplanned Leave" so we need to add "Planned/Unplanned Leave" to the longest one. hope this clears your doubt

Comment: If you need to get all the unique values form all the nested arrays, simply use `Set` together with `Array.prototype.flat()`: `const uniqueValues = [...new Set(graphmonthdata.flat())]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to create a list of all unique values. Afterwards just [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the existing array with the unique values.

```js
const graphmonthdata = [["Bug Fixing","Deployment","Design","Development","Documentation","Downtime","Learning & Skill Upgrade","Meetings","Project Management","Requirement Understanding","Review","Support","Testing"],["Bug Fixing","Deployment","Development","Documentation","Meetings","Review","Support","Testing","UAT/Prod. Fixes"],["Meetings","Organisational Activity","Planned/Unplanned Leave","Testing"]];

const uniqueItems = new Set(graphmonthdata.flat());
const result = graphmonthdata.map(() => [...uniqueItems]);

console.log(result);
```